# How to remove negative values from my multidimesional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am pretty new to javascript,I am little bit confused that how to changy my negative values into 0

```
 var result = [ [ -21, 0 ], [ 22, 0 ], [ -1, 0 ], [ -5, -18 ] ]
console.log(result)//[ [ -21, 0 ], [ -22, 0 ], [ -1, 0 ], [ -5, -18 ] ]
```

I want my output like this

```
[ [ 0, 0 ], [ 22, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var result = [ [ -21, 0 ], [ 22, 0 ], [ -1, 0 ], [ -5, -18 ] ]  
 for (var i=0;i < result.length;i++) { 
        for (var k=0;k < result[i].length;k++) { 
          if (result[i][k] < 0) {
             result[i][k] = 0
          } 
        }
   }
 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

ArtemKh's answer should work.
But just to add on to that, with first for loop you will go through each element of the array you called "result", and with second for you will go through each element of sub-arrays. In if you will check whether a number is negative, and if is, you will set it's value to 0.

Answer (score 0):

For learning purposes, another solution using a more functional style would be as follows:

```js
var arr = [
    [-21, 0],
    [22, 0],
    [-1, 0],
    [-5, -18]
  ],
  result = arr.map(subArr => subArr.map(el => el < 0 ? 0 : el) );
console.log(result);
```

[Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) in JS come with handy functions like [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) or [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). This functions take other functions as callbacks that will be executed over each element of the array in a synchronous manner.

Your problem could be solved "transforming" (or mapping) your array to another one in which every element of the array (which is in turn another array) is "mapped" to "transform" its elements to zero when they are negative.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.prototype.map` nested to iterate over each item in the list. `map` will iterate over an array created a new array from the returned values.

in the last iteration we are checking if the value of x is less than 0, if it is return 0 else return the number.

```js
var result = [ [ -21, 0 ], [ 22, 0 ], [ -1, 0 ], [ -5, -18 ] ]

console.log(
  result.map(r => r.map(x => x < 0 ? 0 : x))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Math.max for the values und iterate the outer and inner array.

```js
var array = [[-21, 0], [22, 0], [-1, 0], [-5, -18]],
    result = array.map(function (a) { 
        return a.map(function (b) { 
            return Math.max(b, 0);
        });
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The same in ES6

```js
var array = [[-21, 0], [22, 0], [-1, 0], [-5, -18]],
    result = array.map(a => a.map(b => Math.max(b, 0)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```